# loading input from multi choice

Tags: asp.net, select, user-input

Hi I have a task as that
a dropdown list to choose an input type 
selections are

- textbox
- datetime
- number

while choosing one of those types, I have to open the selected input(for example if user chose datetime I have to open a datetime input)

For this task which is most suitable

1. using aspview(each input type one view)
2. for each one a usercontrol so when user select
   a type loading it's usercontrol at runtime

or do you have any better ideas?

Comment: You question could do with rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea...

You coulde encapsulate each control in a div and use javascript to change the display of each from none to something.